# Setting the text value of a dropdown keeps resetting

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML declared in a page:

```
<select class="js-basket-qty basketProduct__quantity basketProduct__dropdown">
  <option value="1">1</option> …
</select>
```

The option values go to 10. The classes on the select statement trigger a number of events when you change the value.

 The events all work as expected, but what doesn't happen is the text within the select doesn't stay.

e.g. 1 is set in the select by default. I then select 3 from the dropdown. 

3 get's used by the events being triggered and for a split second I see 3 in the selector text box. However, by the time it's finished, it shows 1 again instead of holding the 3.

So at the end of the events, I'm trying to set the value as the selected value with something like `$('.basketProduct__dropdown').val(qty.toString());`

At the top of my function I have:

```
var basketItem = getBasketItem($(event.currentTarget)),
    qty = parseInt(basketItem.find('.js-basket-qty').val(),10);
……
….
ajaxUpdateBasket({ 
….}).done(render);

$('.basketProduct__dropdown').val(qty.toString());
```

Comment: if you want target by class, should be: `$('.basketProduct__dropdown').val(qty);` with `.`

Comment: "*by the events being triggered*"... can you show us those events? Is there some form that may be reloading the page? Is there an event that rebuild the options? Just this small HTML with some description isn't very useful to us tell you something that can be wrong

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo, yes sorry I missed the period, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @CalvinNunes yes, one of the events does fire a page reload. so I'm trying to set it after the rerender has happened with the above code. I cant really show it here as there are loads of things going on and it would be too much

Comment: Are you returning .val(qty) as a string or a number? I believe it needs to be a string. Also probably worth mentioning that you need to wait until the DOM is ready to process that change. I assume you know that but trying to set something too soon breaks JS all the time.

Comment: @bilpor, please, include that info on your question by [edit]ing it. It is a very important information. Also, please explain how you are setting the value AFTER the page reload and how did you save this value to reuse after reload.

Comment: @BryceHowitson qty as a string. I believe in my code I've made this the last thing to be done. i.e. in the change event an ajax call is made to the server with the value. in the .done event of the js, a re-render takes place. when it returns from that function,that's when I try to do the above.

Comment: i would try with a 1sec timeout, like: var t = setTimeout(function(){ $('.basketProduct__dropdown').val(qty); }, 1000); not necessarily as a final solution, but at least it would give you a clue...If that works it means something else is going on asynchronously

Comment: and all that happens inside $ready()? If the DOM isn't ready it won't change a DOM element `<select>`

Answer (score 0):

Your `ajaxUpdateBasket` method is probably `asynchronous`, so you need to set the `select` value at the end of your `render` function. More like this:

```
    var basketItem = getBasketItem($(event.currentTarget)),
        qty = parseInt(basketItem.find('.js-basket-qty').val(),10);
    ……
    ….
    ajaxUpdateBasket({ 
    ….}).done(render);

    function render(){
        ...some stuff
        $('.basketProduct__dropdown').val(qty.toString());
    }
```

Note that you will need to make sure `qty` is accessible from inside `render()`